# arrange numbers 1 to 10 to the triangles

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual

Arrange numbers 1 to 10 to the UP triangles, with rules :

1. [image: Rules]
2. (-) means absolute difference

**Solve This**:

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: is the solution unique?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry ; Yes, it is unique.

Comment: I think there is no solution, could you check your triangle values and signs please?

Comment: @Oray : I just checked it, all values and signs are correct.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya F-G or it is absolute difference?

Comment: @Oray : absolute diiference

Comment: @JamalSenjaya then you need to emphasize that in your text since your explanation is not like that.

Comment: is divide commutative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

> ```
>       10 
>     2 * 5 
>   8 / 4 - 9 
> 1 + 7 - 3 + 6
> ```

The image version created with my awesome pinta skills.

> [image]

Explanation:

> J can only be 6, 8 or 10.
>  I started with j = 10 randomly.
>  this means H and I can be 2 and 5.
>  I put H =2 since it can be obtained from a fraction (8/4) and 5 cannot.
>  Obviously G = 9.
>  From here see if the rest of the numbers fit.

Comment: "Sorry, I don't know how to hide formatted code." -- You can use `<pre>`, as you did, and then prepend every line in the block with the spoiler markup `>!`.

Comment: @MOehm. Thanks. I tried it but I think I missed the last one and that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try 6, 8 and 10 afterwards?

Comment: @boboquack. No. because the OP stated the solution is unique and I'm lazy. On top of that is Monday morning. I didn't feel like it. :)